# Adding items to an array based on another array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got 3 arrays

```
var arr1 = ["2", "3", "1"],
    arr2 = ["x", "y", "z"],
    arr3 = [];
```

how can I call items from `arr2` into `arr3` according to the `arr1` number order? Example:

```
arr3 = ["y", "z", "x"];
```

Comment: have you try it before posting ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 0 indexed array numbers

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
   arr3.push(arr2[arr1[i]])
}
```

Or since you are using 1 indexed array

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
   arr3.push(arr2[arr1[i] - 1])
}
```

Comment: You probably could, I don't think you need to though since this solution seems easy enough

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var arr1 = ["2", "3", "1"],
    arr2 = ["x", "y", "z"],
    arr3 = [];
arr3=arr1.map(function(i){return arr2[i-1]}); 
console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values of `arr1` do not correspond with keys, like if `arr1 = [50, 4, -2, 999]`, then here is a convoluted answer:

```
arr1.map(function(val, key){ return [val, key] })
    .sort(function(a,b){ return a[0]-b[0] })
    .map(function(a){ return arr2[a[1]] })
```

Comment: i get ` ["z", "y", "x", undefined]` i like your methodology but it should be `["y", "z", "x"]`. did you get the same results as me. if not can you fix the answer.